# WP_Debug not showing output

Tags: wordpress, debugging, mamp

I am not sure where to begin to explain the problem. I had several since I upgraded my MAMP to MAMP Pro, like MAMP turning on caching so I could not see my develop changes immediately and more. 
I went back to the free version of MAMP and found the cache problem, but now this is a new problem:

I just noticed that WP_DEBUG (which is set to true) is not giving any output. Even after adding PHP I know should spit errors.

Does anybody know have any idea in which direction I should have a look? Is it a Wordpress problem or a MAMP problem?

In the php_error.log in MAMP I do see some errors of today, but not for the last few hours, even thought I should have had some errors.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it's a Wordpress plugin (WP Google Maps) causing the issue. It had nothing to do with MAMP